# Firebase Function postId error. Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase functions and have successfully run a sanitize function.

The problem I am having is my firebase database looks like this.

[image: posts.]

The ABC123 and the 0l692lPD6EfqUZ4Y4xiCOVmnNmC2 are both sets automatically when a post is created so I would not know what they will be.

I can hard code the first ABC123 and set {postID} for the second one and it runs successfully. But if I set both to posteId it fails.

below is my code. I need to be able to change the ABC123 to postId because I will not know what it will be in my index.js code.

```
exports.sanitizePost = functions.database
    .ref('/posts/ABC123/question/{postId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const post = event.data.val()
        if (post.sanitized) {
            return
        }
        console.log("Sanitizing new post " + event.params.pushId)
        console.log(post)
        post.sanitized = true
        post.question = sanitize(post.question)
        const promise = event.data.ref.set(post)
        return promise
    })

function sanitize(s) {
    var sanitizedText = s
    sanitizedText = sanitizedText.replace(/\bstupid\b/ig, "wonderful")
    return sanitizedText
}
```

I need `.ref('/posts/ABC123/question/{postId}')` to be `.ref('/posts/{postID}/question/{postId}')` or somthing that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the same parameter twice in a path. But you can have two parameters of different names, e.g.

```
exports.sanitizePost = functions.database
    .ref('/posts/{questionId}/question/{postId}')
```

Comment: Thank you for that this makes sense and worked perfectly